# Mass Update Record Error too many DML

Tags: data-loader

I want to mass update the record of my custom object called Request_Delivery_Plan__c.. There`s 1 trigger called RDP_Create_Delivery_Plan on Request_Delivery_Plan__c..

I set my data loader batch size to "1".. but keep gettin this error :

> RDP_Create_Delivery_Plan: System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

```
trigger RDP_Create_Delivery_Plan on Request_Delivery_Plan__c (after update) {
for(Request_Delivery_Plan__c rdp:Trigger.New){
    //if(trigger.old[0].Revisi__c != rdp.Revisi__c) {
    if(rdp.Create_Detail__c) {
        //TriggerFuture.RDPCreateDPD(rdp.id);

            List<Delivery_Plan_and_Actual__c> dpalist = [SELECT id, Contract_Product__c, Contract2__c, PO_Number__c, Account__c,
                                                     Account_Address__c, Plan_Delivery_Date_ETD__c, Plan_Arrival_Date_ETA__c,
                                                     Product__c FROM Delivery_Plan_and_Actual__c WHERE
                                                     Contract_Product__c=:rdp.Contract_Product__c AND
                                                     Contract2__c=:rdp.Contract__c AND
                                                     PO_Number__c=:rdp.Customer_PO__c AND
                                                     Account__c=:rdp.Account__c AND
                                                     Account_Address__c=:rdp.Account_Address__c AND
                                                     Plan_Delivery_Date_ETD__c=:rdp.ETD__c AND
                                                     Plan_Arrival_Date_ETA__c=:rdp.ETA__c AND
                                                     Company__c =:rdp.Company__c AND
                                                     Product__c=:rdp.Product_Name__c LIMIT 1];

             id dpaid;
             if(dpalist.size()==0){
                Delivery_Plan_and_Actual__c dpa = new Delivery_Plan_and_Actual__c(
                       Contract_Product__c=rdp.Contract_Product__c,
                       PO_Number__c=rdp.Customer_PO__c,
                       Contract2__c=rdp.Contract__c,
                       Account__c=rdp.Account__c,
                       Account_Address__c=rdp.Account_Address__c,
                       Plan_Delivery_Date_ETD__c=rdp.ETD__c,
                       Plan_Arrival_Date_ETA__c=rdp.ETA__c,
                       Company__c = rdp.Company__c,
                       Product__c=rdp.Product_Name__c
                       //Qty_Plan__c=rdp.Revisi__c 
                );
                 insert dpa;
                dpaid=dpa.id;
            }
            else if(dpalist.size()>0){
                 dpaid=dpalist[0].id;
             }
                Delivery_Plan_Detail__c detail = new Delivery_Plan_Detail__c(
                    Request_Delivery_Plan__c=rdp.id,
                    Delivery_Plan_Actual__c=dpaid,
                    ETA__c=rdp.ETA__c,
                    ETD__c=rdp.ETD__c,
                    Product_Name__c=rdp.Product_Name__c,
                    Company__c = rdp.Company__c,
                    Qty_Plan__c=rdp.Revisi__c
                    //Ext_Id__c = RDP.Name+''+RDP.Count_Data__c
                );
                upsert detail;

        Request_Delivery_Plan__c RDP2 = [SELECT id, Name, Contract_Product__c, Contract__c, Customer_PO__c, Account__c, Account_Address__c, ETD__c, ETA__c,
                Product_Name__c, Revisi__c, Qty_Plan__c, Create_Detail__c FROM Request_Delivery_Plan__c
                WHERE id =: RDP.id LIMIT 1];   

        if (RDP2.Qty_Plan__c == NULL) RDP2.Qty_Plan__c = 0;
        RDP2.Qty_Plan__c += rdp.Revisi__c;
        RDP2.Create_Detail__c = FALSE;
        Update RDP2;
        //}
    }//end if    
}
}//end trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a DML statement inside of your for loop (which is a big nono)  you should read about how to [Bulkify Your Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). As to why you are getting other errors even with a insert size of 1. I'm guessing some other process is firing and triggering something else which is having this called again.

Comment: I canceled the update process and got 500+ sucesss , 100+ error (too many dml) how`s this possible?

Comment: I tried to update 1 record manualy, from my object update button.. it works fine, the data updated..  but if I use data loader.. error too many dml.. hmm

Comment: Without having full access to your org I would have no idea what I can tell you is that your trigger is your problem and you really should Bulkify it